# Excel addin deployment through ClickOnce update collapse

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, clickonce, add-in

I developed Excel addin. I want to deploy addin it through ClickOnce. Addin publish to a Shared folder. Addin is developed successfully and appears in Excel. but when I change something in Adin and publish an updated version when you start Excel the following error:

> The customization cannot be installed because another version is
>   currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To
>   install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove
>   Programs to uninstall this program: PricelistExcelAddIn. Then install
>   the new customization from the following location:
>   file:///C:/Users/sribin/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2008/Projects/PricelistExcelAddIn/PricelistExcelAddIn/bin/Debug/PricelistExcelAddIn.vsto

Details:

Name:

> From: file:///C:/Users/sribin/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2008/Projects/PricelistExcelAddIn/PricelistExcelAddIn/bin/Debug/PricelistExcelAddIn.vsto

******* *Exception Text* *********

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException:
>   The customization cannot be installed because another version is
>   currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To
>   install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove
>   Programs to uninstall this program: PricelistExcelAddIn. Then install
>   the new customization from the following location:
>   file:///C:/Users/sribin/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2008/Projects/PricelistExcelAddIn/PricelistExcelAddIn/bin/Debug/PricelistExcelAddIn.vsto
>   в
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySolutionCodebaseIsUnchanged(Uri
>   uri, String subscriptionId, Boolean previouslyInstalled)    в
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The installation URL of a ClickOnce deployment is a major piece of the identity. You can't install a C/O app from two different locations, and you can't install it from a location that doesn't match the installation URL in the deployment. Having said that, what is your installation URL for your VSTO addin? Surely it's not "c:/users/sribin/documents/visual studio 2008/projects..."

Create a file share somewhere, even if it's on your own machine for testing, and use that as your installation URL, and put the files there.